# PHP Arrays, appending depth of array item recursively to an array with the key of 'depth'

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, associative-array

Per the example array at the very bottom, i want to be able to append the depth of each embedded array inside of the array. for example:

```
    array (
      53 => 
      array (
        'title' => 'Home',
        'path' => '',
        'type' => '118',
        'pid' => 52,
        'hasChildren' => 0,
      ),
```

Has a depth of one according to the sample array shown below so it should now look like this:

```
    array (
      53 => 
      array (
        'title' => 'Home',
        'path' => '',
        'type' => '118',
        'pid' => 52,
        'hasChildren' => 0,
        'depth' => 1,
      ),
```

and so on...

All of the recursive array function attempts i have made are pretty embarrassing. However I have looked at RecursiveArrayIterator which has the getDepth function. I'm confused on how to append it to the current array... any help is VERY much appreciated, thank you.

```
 
  array (
    'title' => 'Website Navigation',
    'path' => '',
    'type' => '115',
    'pid' => 0,
    'hasChildren' => 1,
    'children' => 
    array (
      53 => 
      array (
        'title' => 'Home',
        'path' => '',
        'type' => '118',
        'pid' => 52,
        'hasChildren' => 0,
      ),
      54 => 
      array (
        'title' => 'Features',
        'path' => 'features',
        'type' => '374',
        'pid' => 52,
        'hasChildren' => 1,
        'children' => 
        array (
          59 => 
          array (
            'title' => 'artistic',
            'path' => 'features/artistic',
            'type' => '374',
            'pid' => 54,
            'hasChildren' => 1,
            'children' => 
            array (
              63 => 
              array (
                'title' => 'galleries',
                'path' => 'features/artistic/galleries',
                'type' => '374',
                'pid' => 59,
                'hasChildren' => 1,
                'children' => 
                array (
                  65 => 
                  array (
                    'title' => 'graphics',
                    'path' => 'features/artistic/galleries/graphics',
                    'type' => '118',
                    'pid' => 63,
                    'hasChildren' => 0,
                  ),
                  67 => 
                  array (
                    'title' => 'mixed medium',
                    'path' => 'features/artistic/galleries/mixed-medium',
                    'type' => '118',
                    'pid' => 63,
                    'hasChildren' => 0,
                  ),
                  64 => 
                  array (
                    'title' => 'overview',
                    'path' => 'features/artistic/galleries',
                    'type' => '118',
                    'pid' => 63,
                    'hasChildren' => 0,
                  ),
                  68 => 
                  array (
                    'title' => 'photography',
                    'path' => 'features/artistic/galleries/photography',
                    'type' => '118',
                    'pid' => 63,
                    'hasChildren' => 0,
                  ),
                  66 => 
                  array (
                    'title' => 'traditional',
                    'path' => 'features/artistic/galleries/traditional',
                    'type' => '118',
                    'pid' => 63,
                    'hasChildren' => 0,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              62 => 
              array (
                'title' => 'overview',
                'path' => 'features/artistic',
                'type' => '118',
                'pid' => 59,
                'hasChildren' => 0,
              ),
              69 => 
              array (
                'title' => 'tutorials',
                'path' => 'features/artistic/tutorials',
                'type' => '374',
                'pid' => 59,
                'hasChildren' => 1,
                'children' => 
                array (
                  71 => 
                  array (
                    'title' => 'by category',
                    'path' => 'features/artistic/tutorials/by-category/',
                    'type' => '118',
                    'pid' => 69,
                    'hasChildren' => 0,
                  ),
                  72 => 
                  array (
                    'title' => 'by date',
                    'path' => 'features/artistic/tutorials/by-date/',
                    'type' => '118',
                    'pid' => 69,
                    'hasChildren' => 0,
                  ),
                  70 => 
                  array (
                    'title' => 'overview',
                    'path' => 'features/artistic/tutorials',
                    'type' => '118',
                    'pid' => 69,
                    'hasChildren' => 0,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          58 => 
          array (
            'title' => 'overview',
            'path' => 'features',
            'type' => '118',
            'pid' => 54,
            'hasChildren' => 0,
          ),
          61 => 
          array (
            'title' => 'projects / labs',
            'path' => 'features/projects-labs/',
            'type' => '374',
            'pid' => 54,
            'hasChildren' => 0,
          ),
          60 => 
          array (
            'title' => 'web development',
            'path' => 'features/web-development',
            'type' => '374',
            'pid' => 54,
            'hasChildren' => 1,
            'children' => 
            array (
              74 => 
              array (
                'title' => 'articles',
                'path' => 'features/web-development/articles/',
                'type' => '374',
                'pid' => 60,
                'hasChildren' => 0,
              ),
              73 => 
              array (
                'title' => 'overview',
                'path' => 'features/web-development',
                'type' => '118',
                'pid' => 60,
                'hasChildren' => 0,
              ),
              75 => 
              array (
                'title' => 'tutorials',
                'path' => 'features/web-development/tutorials',
                'type' => '374',
                'pid' => 60,
                'hasChildren' => 0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      55 => 
      array (
        'title' => 'Activity',
        'path' => 'activity',
        'type' => '374',
        'pid' => 52,
        'hasChildren' => 0,
      ),
      56 => 
      array (
        'title' => 'Blog',
        'path' => 'blog',
        'type' => '374',
        'pid' => 52,
        'hasChildren' => 0,
      ),
      57 => 
      array (
        'title' => 'About',
        'path' => 'about',
        'type' => '374',
        'pid' => 52,
        'hasChildren' => 1,
        'children' => 
        array (
          76 => 
          array (
            'title' => 'the author',
            'path' => 'about/the-author',
            'type' => '118',
            'pid' => 57,
            'hasChildren' => 0,
          ),
          77 => 
          array (
            'title' => 'the website',
            'path' => 'about/the-website',
            'type' => '118',
            'pid' => 57,
            'hasChildren' => 0,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);

print_r($example);

?>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume there is another array( at the top not included in your example code.
Something like this?

```
function array_set_depth($array, $depth = -1)
{
  $subdepth = $depth + 1;
  if ($depth < 0) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $subarray) {
      $temp[$key] = array_set_depth(($subarray), $subdepth);
    }
  }
  if ($array['hasChildren'] && isset($array['children'])) {
    foreach ($array['children'] as $key => $subarray) {
      $temp[$key] = array_set_depth($subarray, $subdepth);
    }
    $array['children'] = $temp;
  }
  $array['depth'] = $depth;
  return $array;
}
```

Example usage, I set your array to the value $a:

```
$b = array_set_depth($a);
print_r($b);
```

Edit:

To set depth before the children for nice printing you can do this:

```
function array_set_depth($array, $depth = -1)
{
  $subdepth = $depth + 1;
  if ($depth < 0) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $subarray) {
      $temp[$key] = array_set_depth(($subarray), $subdepth);
    }
    return $temp;
  }
  $array['depth'] = $depth;
  if ($array['hasChildren'] && isset($array['children'])) {
    foreach ($array['children'] as $key => $subarray) {
      $temp[$key] = array_set_depth($subarray, $subdepth);
    }
    unset($array['children']);
    $array['children'] = $temp;
  }
  return $array;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

A recursive function like this should do it?

```
function setDepth(&$a, $depth)
{
    $a['depth']=$depth;
    foreach($a as $key=>$value)
    {
        if (is_array($value))
           setDepth($a[$key], $depth+1);
    }

}
```

The thing to note is that the array is passed by reference, so that we can modify it. Note that we also use this reference in the recursive call to setDepth. Although I used foreach for convenience, the $value variable is a copy, and passing that to setDepth would only make short lived changes within the scope of the foreach loop.

Comment: Thats a generic recursive function for arrays. Need some work for this example.

Comment: I modified your code to work like it should. Dunno how to post it.

Answer (score 5):

Modified Pauls code to work with this example.

```
function setDepth(&$a, $depth = -1)
{
    if (($depth > -1) && !($depth % 2))
      $a['depth']= $depth / 2;
    foreach($a as $key=>$value)
    {
        if (is_array($value))
           setDepth($a[$key], $depth+1);
    }

}
setDepth($a);
print_r($a);
```

Answer (score 0):

sth like this should do the trick:

```
function setdepth($arr, $depth = 0)
{
    foreach ($arr as $key => $val)
    {
        $arr[$key]['depth'] = $depth;
        if ($arr[$key]['hasChildren'])
        {
            setdepth(&$arr[$key]['children'], $depth+1);
        }
    }
}
```

i would be easier if your array started with index not with values, so example usage could be like this:

```
$arr[0] = $website;
setdepth(&$arr, 0);
```

where website is the array from your example

Comment: @youdontmeanmuch - do you get any errors? the result is in the $arr variable

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful:

```
function extend( $arr, $myArr=array() ) {

    foreach( $arr as $key => $value ) {
        if( is_array( $key ) ) {
            extend( $arr[ $key ] );
        } else {
            $myArr[ $key ] = $arr[ $key ];
        }
    }

    return $myArr;
}
```

Function called "extend" because it's not only copies array into new one, it can also extends existing arrays.

To extend an array you should put it as the second parameter, otherwise put an empty array.
The function lopps through array properties and checks is it an array or not and if it is function envoked again otherwise it copies values into another array and returns it.